# CBPeripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic, maid synchrone

Tags: ios, multithreading, events, asynchronous, bluetooth

I have a BLE peripheral build over a well known (by me) serial peripheral.
For that serial peripheral i have a whole home maid lib, that implement its serial protocol.
The protocol follow the rule : send a message then immediately receive an answer.

Right. I have re-implemented the communication over bluetooth, using CoreBluetooth.framework and it work not so bad.
My main problem was to wait until the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic was called before considering get the reply.
(Thank you to stackoverflow guys, i have found number of reply here that have save my life)

But now when talking to my device I must do something like :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(m_ProcessingQueue, ^{
        bool ok = [MyPeripheral ExcecuteCommand];
    });

}
```

if i do that :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     bool ok = [MyPeripheral ExcecuteCommand];
}
```

the didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is not called. Execute command times out, and return false. THEN didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is called after all, with good data in it.

I have discorvered that didUpdateValueForCharacteristic is called in the main thread :

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateValueForCharacteristic %@", [NSThread isMainThread]?@"is main thread":@"is NOT main thread"); // wich reply true !
}
```

So if not calling the [MyPeripheral ExcecuteCommand]; in another thread, i get the main thread blocked, and never let didUpdateValueForCharacteristic to be called.

Finally my question is :
Is there any way to make  didUpdateValueForCharacteristic called in a background thread ?

Thank you !